# Fluent Nhibernate One To One mapping issue

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have to tables, table Person and Profile. Profile has the PK of Person as FK.
I also have two classes:

```
public class Person
{
  public int Id
  { 
    get;set;
  }

  public Profile Profile
  { 
    get;set;
  }
}

public class Profile
{
  Public int PersonId
  {
    get;set;
  }

Public string Language
  {
    get;set;
  }
}
```

My mapping is :

```
public class ProfileMap : ClassMap<Profile>
{

    public ProfileSettingsMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.PersonId).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.Language, "LanguageId");
    }
}

public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        HasOne(p => p.ProfileSettings).Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Now, when updating a existing Profile object, it works fine, but when trying to insert a new Profile, im getting:

could not execute batch command.[SQL: SQL not available]

The PersonId is Profile object is 0 (when debugging)

How can i fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you tell NH that you are maintaining the one to one on your own (`GeneratedBy.Assigned()`)

either map it as onetoone

```
public class ProfileMap : ClassMap<Profile>
{

    public ProfileMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.PersonId).GeneratedBy.Foreign("Person"); // assuming you have a reference to Person in Profile
        Map(x => x.Language, "LanguageId");
    }
}

public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        HasOne(p => p.ProfileSettings).Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

or map the profile as Component of Person

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Join("Profiles", join => 
        {
            join.Component(p => p.ProfileSettings, c =>
            {
                c.Map(x => x.LanguageId);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Update: this code in a console app works for me with FNH 1.2

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public virtual int RecordsPerPage { get; set; }
}

public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{ 
    public PersonMap()
    { 
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Join("Profile", join =>
        {
            join.Component(p => p.Profile, c =>
            {
                c.Map(x => x.RecordsPerPage, "RecordsPerPage");
            });
        });
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory().ShowSql())
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.Add<PersonMap>())
        .BuildConfiguration();

    using (var sf = config.BuildSessionFactory())
    using (var session = sf.OpenSession())
    {
        new SchemaExport(config).Execute(true, true, false, session.Connection, null);

        using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            session.Save(new Person { Profile = new Profile { RecordsPerPage = 5 } });
            tx.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Firo, I tried also Id(x => x.PersonId).GeneratedBy.Foreign("Person"); , by first adding a Person property in Profile , this works fine when the person already has a 'Profile' in database, but when trying to save a Person with new Profile, im getting: 'Unable to resolve property: Person' ....Person in Profile is then null and PersonId is 0

Comment: when you assign a new Profile to a person you have to set the person property on the profile, otherwise NH can not save the profile because it can not determine the correct id since the person is not set.

Comment: Firo, If you say in your ProfileMap : Id(x => x.PersonId).GeneratedBy.Foreign("Person");  ...doesn't itmean that PersonId of Profile will be automatically assigned? this happens when the Person already has a Profile.. why not when the Person does not have a Profile?

Comment: `GeneratedBy.Foreign("Person")` means that NH will set `PersonId = Person.Id` after `Person.Id` is set, therefor the property `Person` must be set to the person which the Profile belongs to.

Comment: okay thank you for that..one more issue is, when i try your second suggestion(with Join), im getting this error : The element 'class' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has invalid child element 'joined-subclass' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'. List of possible elements expected: 'join, subclass, loader, sql-insert, sql-update, sql-delete, filter, resultset, query, sql-query' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'.

Comment: can you post your mapping of Person? I have no idea why in your case FNH emits a `<joined-subclass>` instead of a `<join>´ for the `Join` method

Comment: Here is PeronMap: public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
    {
        public PersonMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();         //HasOne(p => p.Profile).Cascade.All();
            Join("Profile", join =>
                {
                    join.Component(p => p.Profile, c =>
                        {
                            c.Map(x => x.RecordsPerPage, "RecordsPerPage");
                        });
                });
        }
    }                             (fyi, when using join, i excluded the mapping of Profile, is this relevant?)